# How to call an apex class and visualforce after every 5 seconds to display updated data

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, actionpoller, polling

I am fetching the cases and their status using SOQL query in my controller and then displaying it on visualforce using pageblock. I want to keep loading the page/query after every 5 seconds, so that if a case gets created/deleted, it automatically shows up on the visualforce page, without me manually refreshing the page. I am using a counter variable and increment counter method, just so I could implement action polling, but it has no other other purpose or relation with my actual usecase.

Here is my working code:

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="CasesAndQueues" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

 <apex:form >  

   <apex:pageBlock id="counter">

     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OpenCases}" var="o" >

        <apex:column value="{!o.CaseNumber}"/>

        <apex:column value="{!o.CreatedDate}"/>

        <apex:column value="{!o.Status}"/>

     </apex:pageBlockTable>

  </apex:pageBlock>

  <apex:actionPoller action="{!incrementCounter}" reRender="counter" interval="5"/>

 </apex:form>
```

Apex Class:

Here is my apex class:

```
public class CasesAndQueues {

Integer count = 0;
public CasesAndQueues(){}
public List<Case> OpenCases;
public List<Case> getOpenCases() {

    Id CaseRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.CASE.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('XYZ').getRecordTypeId();
    List<Case> Cases=[SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, Status FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId =: CaseRecordType and (Status =: 'Ready to Meet' OR Status =: 'New')  ORDER BY Status DESC];

    return Cases;

}

public PageReference incrementCounter() {

    count++;
    return null;

    }


}
```

**Is there a better way to implement polling in my case, instead of using count variable, since it has no purpose in my usecase? Also, the code that I have would it cause governor limit issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to implement polling in my case, instead of using count variable, since it has no purpose in my usecase?

You don't need the counter. You don't even need an action. Your poller could look like:

```
<apex:actionPoller reRender="counter" interval="5"/>
```

> Also, the code that I have would it cause governor limit issue?

No, each polling session is its own transaction, so you only need to worry about breaking the 1,000 row limit for the Visualforce iterator (`apex:pageBlockTable`).

---

Cases probably don't show up every 5 seconds. Consider using the Streaming API, Change Data API, or increasing the polling to a more reasonable value (every 30 seconds or so). If your Visualforce gets backed up because of lag, setting the polling value too low may lock up the browser and/or cause severe lag issues.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. So the usecase is that I am implementing it for one stop, so students would come and in order to look for an agent, they would create a case, whose status would be NEW initially. When agent picks up the case, the status would become 'Ready to meet'. I am trying to display all the open cases and their status(New, ready to meet) in the above visualforce which would be displayed on the monitor.Hence I am using polling to show the updated status at all times.

Comment: I don't think there will be 1000 rows/open cases/students at any given point, so then the code I have already, would that work too or do I still need to implement Steaming API?

Comment: @Student Again, I recommend a longer polling time, 30 seconds should be plenty (that's what we use internally on some of our older pages), and you don't need the counter (which will improve performance). Other than that, your code is just fine.

Comment: Great.I just increased it to 30 seconds. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 5):

Polling every 5 seconds is bad imo and waste of resources. Polling generally slows things down as well.

From what I can see if all you want is a notification for newly created, deleted case. Once you get the notification you can do a query and get the latest data.

And, the best candidate here is [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm),

Just Implement the VF client for streaming api push topics, that will listen to change in data and get your latest data.

There is even a [Sample SF VF code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_generic_vfp_intro.htm) that allow you to kickstart your project.